# Meteor - How to hide meteor version used

Tags: javascript, meteor

I wanted to ask that for security reasons - we should be able to remove the meteor version information from the meteor_runtime_config section from the page source section and other headless browser/curl requests like below:

```
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"METEOR@1.0.3.1"...
```

Especially so that known vulnerabilities are not exploited. This gives developers the some what time to catch to the new version especially with breaking changes to the code.

Here from a [blog post](https://medium.com/meteor-secret/what-ive-found-after-scraping-1740-meteor-apps-99a20ac6d252#.2n98sdhpr) back in 2014, 31 apps were reported to have removed the version number, so it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trick is to empty `__meteor_runtime_config__.meteorRelease` at the startup phase.

```
Meteor.startup( function() {
    __meteor_runtime_config__.meteorRelease = undefined;
});
```

You can also remove the string assigned to `meteorRelease` in `<application>/bundle/programs/server/config.json` before you deploy your application. The information is extracted from that config file, which is generated by Meteor when it builds applications.

Comment: Hey @Season, your trick worked perfectly!!! Thanks so much for giving your elaborate working answer. I just wanted to ask one more thing if its also possible to hide all of the __meteor_runtime_config__ section from the page source?

Comment: @codingbear, Properties of `__meteor_runtime_config__` are created for respective use. I would not try to hide the whole object from clients since most settings in it are of low correlation with security and essential to run Meteor applications.

Comment: Hey @Season, thanks for answering my question in the comment, and I would do likewise. Cheers